# JCA resource adapter not recognized on websphere liberty developer tools

Tags: websphere-liberty, jca, ibm-wdt

I am configuring a JCA resource adapter on Eclipse JEE (Mars) / Websphere Liberty (8.5.5.8) / Websphere Liberty Developer Tools Plugin (8.5.5).

The resource adapter is correctly installed with the following server.xml configuration when server is started (jca 1.7 feature enabled) :

```
<resourceAdapter location="<path_to_my_rar>" />
```

My problem is that the tag  is not recognized in Developer Tools (not validated against schema) so the server.xml has an error.
Same error (in this case just a warning) with `<connectionFactory>` tag not recognized as a configuration element.

Any idea to remove those validation error/warning on server.xml ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed a tooling feature outside of WDT (e.g. using the installUtility) rather than from within WDT, you may need to "refresh" WDT's metadata on the installation.

You can do this by:

#### Refresh runtime (update schema and feature list):

```
 Window -> Show View -> Other -> Server -> Runtime Explorer
 Right click on runtime in Runtime Explorer view and select Edit
 Click on Advanced options in the dialog
 Click the Refresh button
```

#### or:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> SELECT YOUR RUNTIME -> CLICK Edit -> CLICK Advanced options... -> CLICK Refresh
```

Comment: Thanks : it works after refreshing WDT's metadata and revalidating the XML.